# Passing "options" to Tastypie Serializers

Tags: python, django, tastypie

The documentation for Tastypie serializers and custom serializers shows `options` defaulting to `None`:

```
to_json(self, data, options=None):
    options = options or {}
```

But then downstream code doesn't seem to leverage it other than passing it to `to_simple()` which also does nothing with it. There's also no documentation showing how to pass options into these functions. I'd like to be able to pass options here so I can adjust how my serializers work. For example, we have content which references data in GridFS. I want to do something like:

```
/api/v1/foo/?format=custom&gridfs=1
```

And have this:

```
to_custom(self, data, options=None):
    options = options or {}
    if options and 'gridfs' in options:
        ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll want to implement your own serializer, as explained here:
http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#camelcase-json-serialization

You'll also want to override the `create_response` function in your resource, which calls `serialize`:
https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L1174

You can turn pass in `options` to serialize here, which will propagated down. For instance:

```
    def create_response(self, request, data, response_class=HttpResponse, **response_kwargs):
        """
        Extracts the common "which-format/serialize/return-response" cycle.

        Mostly a useful shortcut/hook.
        """
        desired_format = self.determine_format(request)
        serialized = self.serialize(request, data, desired_format, options=request.GET)
        return response_class(content=serialized, content_type=build_content_type(desired_format), **response_kwargs
```

For completeness, `serialize` is also called in error response here: https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L1210

Comment: I have a custom one implemented. It's not about making a custom one, it's about how to pass "options" into them. You'll notice in the example you linked that they pass "options" into their to_json() function but it's not used and is always None. I want to know how to pass options in so my to_*() functions in my custom serializer can be changed based on the API call that uses them.

Comment: Ah I see, I updated my answer above with some details on how to propagate "options" down to the serialize method, and how to make "options" be the request's query params!

Comment: Genius and a scholar! Works as advertised! Now I just need to make my own resource so I can inherit this and not copy create_response everywhere!